# Django Form Ajax no refresh

Tags: python, django, ajax, forms

I have been trying to develop a form within detailview, which I did.
Now I would like it to send data to the database and to display the new data on the same page without refreshing.

So I found a way to send the data to the database without refreshing, however, when it comes to display the new data without refreshing it does not work.

I followed this tutorial :
[tutorial from red eye coder club](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxvtUr3Cmto)

Here is my code.

models.py

```
class ImportantFacts(models.Model):
    collection_important_facts = models.ForeignKey(Collection,
        related_name="has_important_facts", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=400, verbose_name='Note')
```

forms.py

```
class ImportantFactsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImportantFacts
        fields = ['note']
```

views.py

```
class CollectionDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Collection
    form_class = ImportantFactsForm
    template_name = 'taskflow/collection_detail.html'
    success_url = None


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CollectionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['important_facts'] = ImportantFactsForm()
        return context


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ImportantFactsForm(request.POST)
        tgt = self.get_object()

        if form.is_valid():
            new_fact = form.save(commit=False)
            new_fact.collection_important_facts = tgt
            new_fact.save()
            return JsonResponse({'fact': model_to_dict(new_fact)}, status=200)
        else:
            return redirect('taskflow:collection_all')
```

facts.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("createFactForm").click(function() {
    var serializedData = $("#createFactForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: $("createFactForm").data('url'),
        data: serializedData,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
          $("#canal1").append('<div class="card mb-1"><div class="card-body">' +   response.fact.note + '<button type="button" class="close float-right"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></div>')
        }
    })

    $("#createFactForm")[0].reset();

  });
});
```

collection_detail.html

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="Canal1">

    <form class="justify-content-center mx-3" id="createFactForm" method="post" data-url="{% url 'taskflow:collection_detail' pk=object.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          {{important_facts.note|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="createButton">Enregistrer</button>
     </form>

     {% if object.has_important_facts %}
       {% for fact in object.has_important_facts.all %}

          <div class="card mb-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              {{fact.note}}
              <button type="button" class="close float-right">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>


        {% endfor %}
       {% endif %}

     </div>
```

I'd like to add that i did not finish the tutorial since I am stuck at the step where I should be able to display new data on the same page without refreshing.

Thanks a lot for your help !

**EDIT 1**

After the suggested below this is what I get in the console:

1. After adding your first suggested code : fact: Object { id: 51, collection_important_facts: 52, note: "New test"
2. With your second suggested code : "Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the output of the request on your console?

Try first:

```
$.ajax({
        url: $("createFactForm").data('url'),
        data: serializedData,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response)
        }
    })
```

Maybe it has something to do with the format of the response, if this is the case, you shoul try:

```
$.ajax({
        url: $("createFactForm").data('url'),
        data: serializedData,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
          var resp = JSON.parse(response);
          console.log(resp)
        }
    })
```

And lets see what happen..

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I tried what you suggested and this is the result : 

1) After adding your first suggested code : fact: Object { id: 51, collection_important_facts: 52, note: "New test"

2) With your second suggested code : "Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Thanks !

Comment: So, it looks that your code worked fine and theres no need for more parse,... You just need to access your json "response" as a normal json object

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I think that my Jason object in my code is rendered with « response.fact.note » so what do I do wrong? What would you do instead ? Thanks again.

Comment: Solution : juste change #canal1 to #Canal1..... 24 hours for this simple syntax error. Thanks anyway !